# MYSQL STORED PROCEDURE - What is the proper way to write this store procedure in MYSQL - I am getting 1064 error

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Please What is the proper way to write this store procedure in MYSQL - I am getting 1064 error from phpmyadmin

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Correct VARCHAR(50)
    SELECT @Correct = answer FROM tbl_questions WHERE id = @getid
    SELECT  CASE @Correct
            WHEN 'OptionOne' THEN (SELECT OptionOne FROM tbl_questions WHERE id = @getid)
            WHEN 'OptionTwo' THEN (SELECT OptionTwo FROM tbl_questions WHERE id = @getid)
            WHEN 'OptionThree' THEN (SELECT OptionThree FROM tbl_questions WHERE id = @getid)
            WHEN 'OptionFour' THEN (SELECT OptionFour FROM tbl_questions WHERE id = @getid)
    END Answer
    FROM tbl_questions
    WHERE id = @getid;
END;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please format your code using Markdown to make it easier to read. More info: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Comment: Please edit your question and add the full text of the error message. If it indicates a specific line in your code by line number, indicate which line in the code it's referencing.

Comment: Also, add a ; after each command (like at the end of declare and at the end of first select.